# Angular controller global vs. closure

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This issue drives me mad.

Test code:

```
describe('controller', function(){
   module('controllers');
   var createCtrl;
   beforeEach(inject(function($injector){

    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
    createCtrl = function(){
     return $controller('controller', {
       $scope: $rootScope
     });
  }));
  it('should create a controller', function(){
    var ctrl = createCtrl();
  });
});
```

It works if i controller function is defined in global scope e.g.

```
angular.module('controllers', [])
   .controller('controller', ['$scope', controller]);
 function controller($scope){}
```

But if i move the function itself to the array, or wrap module code in a closure (in any combination of these):

```
(function(angular){
  angular.module('controllers', [])
  .controller('controller', ['$scope', function($scope){}]);
})(angular);
```

test starts to throw this error 
`Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'controller' is not a function, got undefined`

Any ideas? I really need this controller not to pollute global scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to fix a syntax issue. The function assigned to `createCtrl` is missing a closing curly bracket.

To fix your actual issue you need to include angular-mocks and replace

```
module('controllers');
```

with

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('controllers'));
```

Moving the function itself into the array seems totally valid, I personally use this syntax all the time. Wrapping them in a closure seems unnecessary though, since you're not exposing any variables.

I also recommend not using the $rootScope as the current $scope. Instead use `$rootScope.$new()`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I still cannot understand what is the difference between module() and mock.module() when i do not actually mock something, but this helped for some reason. Thanks.